# Postgres - Adding big serial to an existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with Millions of rows and I'd like to add a bigserial column to the table so that I can change our uuid id implementation to bigserial

```
ALTER TABLE "table_1" add column "serial_id" BIGSERIAL
```

I tried the above sql and it works, the only problem is that it blocks all operations on the table until it has added serial for all. Which means downtime on my application

Comment: As a side note: the use of serial/bigserial is discouraged in favour of the standard compliant `identity` columns.

Answer (score 1):

There may not much you can do. That command has to update every row in the table. However, the following sequence of commands may work for you. It essentially accomplishes what defining a column as BIGSERIAL actually does. NOTE: Although BIGSERIAL occupies the data type in the column definition it is not is not a data type. It is a shortcut for create sequence, define column as bigint, and set the sequence as the column default. So:

- `alter table table_1 add column serial_id bigint;`
- `create sequence table_1_seq bigint;`
- Update in batches;

```
with id_list (rowid) as 
     (select ctid 
        from table_1
       where serial_id is null
        limit 10000            -- or whatever batch size desirded
     ) 
update table_1 
   set serial_id = nextval('table_1_seq') 
 where ctid = (select rowid 
                 from id_list
              );
```

- `alter table table_1 alter column serial_id set default nextval('table_1_seq');`
     (**AFTER ALL rows have been updated**).

But now - WHY? If this table has FK to it you now need to either add a bigint column column to each, update each, make the new column the PK in table_1 and update each FK, update the new column in each table to the `serial_id` for the corresponding uuid in table_1, drop the PK in table_1 and the FK, reestablish table_q PK and each FK, and that may not be all. OR You can keep both existing UUID as a unique constant (perhaps reestablishing the FK relationships) - and you *have gained nothing* just added more overhead. Is it really worth it.